# why does it pop an error when I already set a rule in while?

Tags: python, while-loop, helper

I already set if weight and height isn't an integer, ask to user to input it again. but it pop: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" instead". thanks for helping

```
while type(weight) != int and type(height) != int and weight not in weightrange and height not in heightrange:

        weight = int(input("Enter a weight number please (kg): "))

        height = int(input("Enter a height number please (cm): "))
```

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" instead` error seems to be in converting your input to int.

Comment: What it's telling you is that the string that was input was not, in fact, a number.  Two things to remember: the `while` statement will execute before there is any input, and `type(weight) != int` does NOT check that a string can be converted to an integer.

Comment: @votelessbubble but when i delete int(), it keeps on repeating even though I input a number

Comment: Yes, that is expected because by default the input is in string type.

Comment: @TimRoberts for context I set (weight = '') so does it check what's inside '  ' before going through while ?

Comment: Well, sort of.  The `while` expression is evaluated before entering the loop and at the end of each loop.  It won't check what's "inside" `weight`.  Just that `type(weight) != int` and that `weight not in weightrange`.

Comment: Is this homework?  I assume you're computing BMI.  Do you have a file of test values?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm making a basketball position suggester, and let the user input their weight and height, but i'm preventing input such as words and not sensible values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to jump in, because I think you're on the wrong track.  You must remember that things execute IN ORDER, from top to bottom.  You can't "establish a rule" and hope that the rule will be applied in the future.  Python just doesn't work that way.  Some languages do, Python does not.

```
while True:
    weight = input("Enter a weight number please (kg): ")
    if weight.isdigit():
        weight = int(weight)
        if weight in weightrange:
            break
        else:
            print( "Weight not in range.")
    else:
        print( "Please enter an integer.")
while True:
    height = input("Enter a height number please (cm): ")
    if height.isdigit():
        height = int(height)
        if height in heightrange:
            break
        else:
            print( "Height not in range.")
    else:
        print( "Please enter an integer.")
```

If you were doing this for real, you would probably create a function to avoid typing all of that twice.

Comment: when i intentionally put a string in, it shows "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" still, and when i put a number in, it shows :"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'"

Comment: My fault, I forgot to remove the `int` call in the `input` line.  If we're going to validate the input, then we can't automatically call the `int` conversion.

Comment: It works!, so what you're telling me is I shouldn't group them up in a line of code but to spread it out?

Comment: The disadvantage of your method is that you always require BOTH entries.  If they entered a proper weight but a bogus height, they have to enter the weight again.  Also, if they enter something that's not an integer, it will explode with an exception instead of asking again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this,

```
while True:
  try:
    weight = int(input("Enter a weight number please (kg): "))
    height = int(input("Enter a height number please (cm): "))
    break
    
  except:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

You can modify this to fit your height and weight ranges too.